# How to use Rolling OLS in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS


# y = ax^2 + bx + c
def rolling_ols(x, y, window_size):
    x_upper = sm.add_constant(np.column_stack((x, x**2)))
    model = RollingOLS(y, x_upper, window_size)
    results = model.fit()
    params = results.params
    return params[0], params[1], params[2]


# window_size
size = 12

# test_data
test_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': np.arange(100),
        'y': np.random.randn(100)
    }
)

# output
df = test_df.select(
    'x',
    'y',

    # TODO
    # c, b, a = rolling_ols(x, y, window_size=size)
    # y_hat = c + b * 12 + a * 12^2
)
```

Is the custom function `rolling_ols` in the code above correct for calculating the coefficients of an equation of the form `y = ax^2 + bx + c` ?

**How can I use the results of `params[0]`, `params[1]`, `params[2]` i.e. `c`, `b`, `a` in the DataFrame of polars, assuming a scrolling window of `12`, to get a column of results `y_hat`?**

polars version = 0.17.12,statsmodels version = 0.14, numpy version = 1.24.2

Comment: Something with [`rolling_apply`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_apply.html#polars-expr-rolling-apply) seems to be what you want. You can use `functools.partial` to bake in the window_size positional argument.

Answer (score 0):

To test this, set the `window_size` of rolling in `rolling_apply` instead of using RollingOLS directly in statsmodels, and also convert the Series type of polars to `numpy.ndarray` using the `to_numpy` method so that so that statsmodels can be used.

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

# window_size
size = 12

# test_data
np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.random(100)
x = np.array(np.arange(1, len(y) + 1))
test_df = pl.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})


# y = ax^2 + bx + c
def sm_ols(data_x, data_y):
    data_y = data_y.to_numpy()
    length = len(data_x)
    x_upper = np.vstack([np.ones(length), data_x, data_x ** 2]).T
    model = sm.OLS(data_y, x_upper)
    results = model.fit()
    params = results.params
    return params[0] + length * params[1] + length ** 2 * params[2]


# output
df = test_df.select(
    'x',
    'y',

    # TODO
    pl.col('y')
    .rolling_apply(
        lambda s: sm_ols(
            np.arange(1, size + 1),
            s
        ),
        window_size=size
    )
    .alias('t')
)
print(df)
```